# What does mean Public questions tagged

Tags: support

I have set filter on questions tagged. but today I saw there is title saying

> Public questions tagged [c# or asp.net-mvc or jquery or sql or
>   sql-server or asp.net or javascript]

What does mean by public? Is there another category of question exist? I mean Private.

[image]